# Sparql: Get Count of individuals based on a condition over a data property value

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl

I'm new to sparql and I was wondering how to perform the following task :

My data :

```
base url PREFIX fff:<...>

classes:
Artwork
Site
Category

object prop:
site hasArtwork Artwork 
site hasCategory Category

data prop:
Artwork kkk:conservationState xsd:string  (bad, good...)
```

I want to get the count of museums that have more than 10 Artworks in a good conservationState. Getting their names would also be cool but I have no clue if it is possible.

So far, I know only how to count how many sites have an artwork in bad state

```
    SELECT (COUNT(?site) AS ?count) WHERE {
        ?site a fff:Site;
              fff:hasCategory fff:Museum;
              fff:hasArtwork ?artwork;
        ?artwork pgt:conservationState "bad"^^xsd:string.
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: you should `group by` the museum, `count` the artworks and use `having` clause to filter on the grouped data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To output the museums with their artwork count, add `?site` to your `SELECT`, count the artworks, and add a [`GROUP BY`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#groupby) to group by the sites (which means that there will be one result per site):

```
SELECT ?site (COUNT(?artwork) AS ?artwork_count) 
WHERE {
  ?site a fff:Site ;
        fff:hasCategory fff:Museum ;
        fff:hasArtwork ?artwork .
  ?artwork pgt:conservationState "bad"^^xsd:string .
} 
GROUP BY ?site
```

If you want to output additional properties about each museum (e.g., its name), you have to add these properties to the `GROUP BY`, too.

### Properties of counted items

If you want to output properties about the counted artworks (e.g., their names), you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` in your `SELECT`:

```
SELECT ?site (COUNT(?artwork) AS ?artwork_count) (GROUP_CONCAT(?artwork_name; SEPARATOR=", ") AS ?artwork_names)
```

The values will then all be in the same column/cell, separated e.g. by comma.

### Filter by count

To only output museums with an `?artwork_count` higher than 10, you can add [`HAVING`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#having) after the `GROUP BY`:

```
HAVING( ?artwork_count > 10 )
```